# Appium cannot click on google Search button

Tags: appium-ios

I use Xcode 9.3, Appium desktop 1.6.2, i run safari on simulator 
I try to enter to google page and i do a search (sendkey) but i cannot click on Search button

```
private IOSDriver driver;

@Before
public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
    DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "11.3");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone x");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("browserName", "Safari");
  //  desiredCapabilities.setCapability("nativeWebTap", true);
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("udid", "39789C6E-6119-47CC-BD2D-883F491EE93B");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("automationName", "XCUITest");
    //desiredCapabilities.setCapability("app", "/Users/faroukrahem/Downloads/IntactInsuranceDebug.ipa");
    //desiredCapabilities.setCapability("xcodeOrgId", "N2E34G93LZ");
    //desiredCapabilities.setCapability("xcodeSigningId", "iPhone Developer");
    URL remoteUrl = new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub");

    driver = new IOSDriver(remoteUrl, desiredCapabilities);
}

@Test
public void sampleTest() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("farouk rahem");
    driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();
    Thread.sleep(10000);

}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    driver.quit();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Better to use Accessibility Id instead of name or else you can ask your developers to provide unique accessibilityId for that element.